# Attributes added by custom ModelMetadataProvider are not being considered in model-binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, asp.net-core-3.1

Disclaimer: this is a long one. Unreasonable knowledge of ASP.NET Core MVC internals is almost certainly required. Here be dragons.

---

#### Background

I am trying to implement a method for augmenting type metadata in ASP.NET MVC Core.

The reason I want to do this is that my data models are used by multiple projects, so I've shared them by placing them in a NuGet package:

```cs
// defined in NuGet package
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyNestedModel NestedModel { get; set; }
}

public class MyNestedModel
{
    public bool NestedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>^ Listing 1</sup>

However, some of the projects will need to apply additional metadata to the model types - for example, in the case of an ASP.NET Core project, these models will be used as inputs and therefore participate in model-binding, so they require `FromQuery`, `FromHeader` etc. attributes applied. I obviously cannot do this in the package, as different consumer projects will need to apply different attributes depending on their use cases.

The simplest and mostly guaranteed-to-work way is to modify all model properties to be `virtual` and then have subclasses that override those properties as necessary to add attributes:

```cs
// defined in NuGet package
public class MyModel
{
    public virtual int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual MyNestedModel NestedModel { get; set; }
}

public class MyNestedModel
{
    public virtual bool NestedProperty { get; set; }
}

// defined in ASP.NET MVC project consuming above package
public class MyViewModel : MyModel
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "foo")]
    public override int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public new // can't use override, as type is different
        MyNestedViewModel NestedModel { get; set; }
}

[Bind(Prefix = "")]
public class MyNestedViewModel : MyNestedModel
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "bar")]
    public override bool NestedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>^ Listing 2</sup>

**I don't want to do this**, because in every model that has a child model property, that child model has to be subclassed, and then it cannot be used as an override but has to be re-declared with `new` - and the semantics of `new` won't work for me here. Also, I don't really intend for the model types to be subclassed.

I'm aware of [`ModelMetadataTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelmetadatatypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but the intended usage of that attribute is on the model type **to be augmented**, not the type **doing the augmenting**. Since in my case there's no way to know ahead of time what the actual metadata types will be (as they're defined in the consuming projects), I cannot use `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute`. Subclasses and partial classes will also not work - `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute` only applies to the class specified, `partial` cannot span across assemblies.

#### Solution

Essentially, a "reverse" version of `ModelMetadataTypeAttribute` that is applied on the type **doing the augmenting**, pointing back to the model type **to be augmented**:

```cs
// defined in ASP.NET MVC project consuming package from Listing 1
[ReverseModelMetadataType(typeof(MyModel))]
public class MyModelMetadata
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "foo")]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyNestedModel NestedModel { get; set; }
}

[ReverseModelMetadataType(typeof(NestedModel))]
[Bind(Prefix = "")]
public class NestedModelMetadata
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "bar")]
    public bool NestedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>^ Listing 3</sup>

The intention is that at runtime, the model-binding infrastructure will pick up that `MyModel.MyProperty` should be bound using `[FromQuery(Name = "foo")]`, i.e. from the query string as a variable named `foo`. Similarly, `MyModel.NestedModel.NestedProperty` should be simply bound as `bar` from the query string.

In order to make this work I've implemented a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` that inherits [`DefaultModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and overrides the [`CreatePropertyDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelmetadataprovider.createpropertydetails?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_Metadata_DefaultModelMetadataProvider_CreatePropertyDetails_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_Metadata_ModelMetadataIdentity_) method:

```cs
// defined in same ASP.NET Core MVC project as Listing 3
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DefaultModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override DefaultMetadataDetails[] CreatePropertyDetails(ModelMetadataIdentity key)
    {
        var defaultPropertyDetails = base.CreatePropertyDetails(key);

        // check if the key.ModelType should be augmented
        // if so, mutate the relevant element(s) of the defaultPropertyDetails array to do the augmentation

        return defaultPropertyDetails;
    }
}
```

The mutation part effectively changes the relevant `DefaultMetadataDetails.ModelAttributes` member to have the additional attributes applied to the properties of the type(s) decorated with `ReverseModelMetadataTypeAttribute`. I then get ASP.NET MVC Core to use my provider instead of its `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` via the following in `Startup.cs#ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IModelMetadataProvider, MyModelMetadataProvider>();
```

I have verified that provider is registered and the mutation code works correctly: `MyModelMetadataProvider.CreatePropertyDetails` is hit and the `defaultPropertyDetails` returned do contain the extra attributes applied by my `*ModelMetadata` classes from Listing 3.

---

#### Problem

**Model binding does not work:** ASP.NET Core MVC essentially behaves as if the attributes added via Listing 3 do not exist, and I don't know why. As far as I'm aware, the results of the calls to the various `IModelMetadataProvider` methods are cached then used for all subsequent lookup of metadata that's required, including for the purposes of binding models.

I'm hoping that somebody can provide some advice on how to get this to work, before I have to go through the pain of stepping through the ASP.NET Core source myself.